# Swapping between two div classes in foreach

Tags: php, variables

I am currently coding a page based on a json query.

Here is a snippet of the code, I don't want to give the top half as that is grabbing the remote json with id's and passwords, but here is the main snippet:

```
$content_size = 'one_half';

foreach ( $json_decoded['fixtures-results']['matches'] as $match ){
display_match($match); 
}

function display_match($match){
global $content_size; 
if (strtotime($match['date']) < time()) { goto skip; }
$home_team_name = strtolower($match['home-team']['name']);
$home_team_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_',$home_team_name);

$away_team_name = strtolower($match['away-team']['name']);
$away_team_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_',$away_team_name);
$match_date = date("M jS, Y", strtotime($match['date']));
echo '<div class="'.$content_size.'">';
echo '<div class="latest_results" style="background:#ffffff">';
echo '<h6>'.$match_date.', '.$match['status']['full'].'</h6>';
echo '<div class="latest_results_col"><img src="/team_logos/'.$home_team_name.'.png"><span>'.$match['home-team']['name'].'</span></div>';
echo '<div class="latest_results_col goalscore2">vs</div>';
echo '<div class="latest_results_col"><img src="/team_logos/'.$away_team_name.'.png"><span>'.$match['away-team']['name'].'</span></div>';
echo '<div class="clear">';
echo '<span>Location:'.$match['venue'].'</span>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
if ($content_size == "one_half") { $content_size = "one_half_last"; goto skip; }else{ $content_size = "one_half"; goto skip; }
skip:
}
```

What i want is the first div class to be `one_half` then the next one as `one_half_last` then back to `one_half` and so on.

The result is the first div has the class `one_half` but the second has no class, then the third has `one_half` and so on, so you see it seems to be working, except its missing the second, fourth, sixth ect class.

Any help would be greatly received.

Kind Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened, and why it corrected itself, but here is the code i ended up using.

```
$content_size = 'one_half';

foreach ( $json_decoded['fixtures-results']['matches'] as $match ){
display_match($match); 
}

function display_match($match){
global $content_size; 
if(!$content_size){ $content_size = "one_half"; }
if (strtotime($match['date']) < time()) { goto skip; }
$home_team_name = strtolower($match['home-team']['name']);
$home_team_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_',$home_team_name);

$away_team_name = strtolower($match['away-team']['name']);
$away_team_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_',$away_team_name);
$match_date = date("M jS, Y", strtotime($match['date']));

$home_team_name_2 = team_name_2($match['home-team']['name']);
$away_team_name_2 = team_name_2($match['away-team']['name']);
echo '<div class="'.$content_size.'">';
echo '<div class="latest_results" style="background:#ffffff">';
echo '<h6>'.$match_date.', '.$match['status']['full'].'</h6>';
echo '<div class="latest_results_col"><img src="/team_logos/'.$home_team_name.'.png"><span>'.$home_team_name_2.'</span></div>';
echo '<div class="latest_results_col goalscore2">vs</div>';
echo '<div class="latest_results_col"><img src="/team_logos/'.$away_team_name.'.png"><span>'.$away_team_name_2.'</span></div>';
echo '<div class="clear">';
echo '<span>Location:'.$match['venue'].'</span>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
if ($content_size == "one_half") { $content_size = "one_half last_column"; goto skip; }else{ $content_size = "one_half"; goto skip; }
skip:
}
```

If anyone has any idea what I did differently I am happy to hear as I am not sure what i did.